# Prepared Statements and SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am in the process of creating a reply ticket system, and came across this. Since I'm using`mysqli_real_escape_string`, it's adding backslashes to the reply text. Since I'm using prepared statements and `bind_param`, is it safe to remove the mysqli escape string? or will that open it up for SQL injection? Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, didn't know if that applied, I'll take a look! Thank you!

Comment: If you're (properly) using prepared statements, then you DON'T escape. That essentially double-escapes the data.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, no. SQL injection involves inputting strings that are used as part of the SQL control itself rather than values for a part of the query. By parameterizing the query, you essentially cordon off the variable, which covers the cases protected by *_escape_string calls and is more secure.